# Hide an element and show another element on submit a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, go

In a web page, I would like to hide the form on submit (either by clicking or pressing enter) and shows the results. It does not work when the Go web server is run.

When I check the HTML file (without running the Go file), it works. But, when I run the Go code, it shows it quickly and goes to the initial state.

The HTML (Bootstrap) code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">

    <title>TEST</title>
    <!-- favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../static/images/favicon.png">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/style.css" />

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particlesjs/2.2.3/particles.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #2f3b5a
        }

        .table thead th,
        .table td,
        .table th {
            border: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #c83660;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- background particles -->
    <canvas class="background" style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; z-index: -1;"></canvas>

    <div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-column justify-content-center text-white" style="width:100%;">
        <h1 class="display-4">TOOL</h1>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <form class="forms">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <select class="selectpicker forms" name="query">
                                    <option selected>Query Type</option>
                                    <option value="any">Any</option>
                                    <option value="aaaa">A Record</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control forms" name="host" placeholder="Type here...">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button type="button forms" class="btn"><i class="fas fa-search"
                                        aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div id="result" style="display:none;">
                        <table class="table table-borderless">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Record</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Value</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>A</td>
                                    {{range .Arecord}}
                                    <td>{{.}}</td>
                                    {{end}}
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--scripts loaded here-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/80c543b9b1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.13.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/bassjobsen/affix/master/assets/js/affix.js"></script>

    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            Particles.init({
                selector: '.background',
                // red, blue, yellow
                color: ['#f76262', '#216583', '#f6d365'],
                maxParticles: 130,
                connectParticles: true,
                responsive: [
                    {
                        breakpoint: 768,
                        options: {
                            maxParticles: 80
                        }
                    }, {
                        breakpoint: 375,
                        options: {
                            maxParticles: 50
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
        };



        $("form").on("submit", function (e) {
            //e.preventDefault();
            $("form").remove();
            $("#result").show("slow");
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I expect removing the form on submit and shows the results table but as long as I run the code in Go, it just restarts the page (quickly shows the results but) the form value is empty.

```
url := r.FormValue("host")
```

Comment: Submitting a form necessarily causes the browser to send something to the server, clearing what's on the page. Since your `form` has no `action` it submits the form to the current URL, and reloads the page. You had the right idea with `e.preventDefault()`, but of course that prevents submission of the form. You may want to [read up on what happens when you submit a form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data).

Answer (score 1):

I may be totally off here, because I don't think I understand your problem completely, however it looks like  you're trying to submit this form, and then display the results section without the form. I'm guessing your Go server is somehow preparing these results based on the form values.

If that is really the case, then what's happening is that you submit the form, your javascript hides the form and shows the empty results section, then your server prepares the results, and you display the form again. This time though, it is a completely new page and, it has no knowledge of the Javascript executed before form submission. It is a fresh new page, so it'll show the empty form, and not the results section.

If what I understand is correct, then what you should do is to change your template so that it knows it is displaying the results, so it builds the result section without `display: none`.

Comment: +1. You have understood the issue well. If I have understood well, by deleting `display: none` then the result will be shown in the same page below the form (even before there is any result = before the form filled). It is not the thing I am looking for. I want data be shown in a new page.

Comment: Then organize your template so that it either displays the form, or the results, depending on a flag, say, resultFlag. You can have {{if .resultFlag}} <resultsSection> {{else}} <formSection{{end}} in your template, and have it generate two different pages based on state

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should use ajax call to send the request instead of form submit and based upon the response, display the result show/hide.